# Issue with installing ZoKrates on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, zokrates

I am trying to install ZoKrates from **source** to use in my CMD in windows 10 following this guide ***https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html***, but I am getting stuck at the following command:

- cargo build -p zokrates_cli --release

Everything works but the download is stuck at 488/499 as seen in the picture below:

[image]

I tried deleting ZoKrates and starting from scratch, but it doesn't work. It gets stuck on the same percentage again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Worked after waiting a whole hour